# Create a file that's really a network port

Tags: files, filesystems, serial-port

I have a program running on a cluster, and the output of the program is written to a log file which I specify.  However, instead of writing it to a file, I want to write it to a network port, so that it can be read with e.g. Node.js.

For example, I want to be able to specify a file along the lines of /dev/127.0.0.1:3000

Currently, I'm using Node.js to watch the log file, re-read all the data when it changes, compare the new data with the old data to see what was added, and then process that.  But that's quite inefficient.

Comment: If you have bash, ksh, or zsh, and can structure your program so it writes its output to an open file descriptor, say, stdout, you could try `program_name > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/3000`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, `/dev/tcp/`????

Comment: @vonbrand Yes, /dev/tcp is interpreted specially by many modern shells. They don't actually access anything in the /dev filesystem.

Answer (score 6):

If your program is logging without recreating the file (by opening it) you should be able to do it by creating the file as a pipe:

```
mkfifo potato.log
```

You can send message to the pipe as if you were writing to the file:

```
$ # This is the logging process:
$ echo "Warning!" > potato.log
```

And read them:

```
$ # This is the listener process:
$ cat potato.log
Warning!
```

If you really want to forward this to a TCP socket you can do something like:

```
$ socat PIPE:potato.log TCP:localhost:3000
```

It might not be very robust but you should be able to do something more robust by writing a program instead of socat (handling deconnections from the remote TCP).

(all of this is not necessary if you can modify the program to have native support for socket-based logging).